# Stop http resource be accessed by flash

Tags: flash, security, http, cross-domain, web

I have some audio streaming resources on my HTTP server, let's say

http://example.com:7000/foo.mp3

I did design a flash player for playing it.

http://example.com/player.swf

And I noticed that some guys use third-party flash player to play that audio.

http://other.com/player.swf

Their player will try to reload that resource until it's available. This makes a lots of stress to my HTTP server. To stop them from hamming my server, I want to allow access only from my flash player. Strangely, I think in this case, flash player should check the crossdomain.xml first before load my audio resource, but they didn't. They just load the sound and play. The corssdomain.xml is not even there. I try to add one, it doesn't work as well

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.example.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

So what's wrong with the flash player? Why it can access the resource without check crossdomain.xml?

Is that in some cases, flash player doesn't have to check crossdomain.xml? If it is, how can I stop my resource be accessed by third-party players (from different domain)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests made from `Sound` class effectively ignore crossdomain policies. That's an old living bug, Adobe didn't fix in ages. This "feature" is often times used when you need to only send data to server, but you don't expect any response. That is, the player will prevent you from getting the response from a server that doesn't provide policy file, but will send the request anyway.

Now, if you you are trying to protect yourself against a ddos attack - that is a completely different issue, the attacker will most likely use something other than flash player to launch such an attack. Flash player networking API are somewhat lacking / restricting for this kind of activity...

If you require authentication for serving the files, then probably HTML / cookie based solution is not ideal / will not always work, as you may want sometimes to serve the file w/o using html / what if a hacker creates a legitimate session / cookie? You could use two-components encryption (RSA for instance) to generate the key pairs, one for the authorized user and the other for the server. Require the user's key to be supplied with the request for the data as well as credentials. If the user is not registered with the service, the user's part of the key combined with the server's part of the key will not generate user's credentials (or whatever data you encrypted using the keys) - which will signal a fraud attempt. Then it is up to you to block the requester etc. This way is a rock-solid, no more-savvy-hacker-can-bypass kind of approach. If the hacker is not authorized, then she will not get the data in this century :)

If you don't require authentication, then, probably, cookie / session based approach would be appropriate (which means that the data access will be still vulnerable, yet more difficult to get to).

Oh, I just realized that rather too many requests is the issue. Then, well, why wouldn't you "satisfy" the requests, if you can already find out they aren't going to get any real data, with say, serving them a file one Terrabyte big? :) Or maybe send them some records of Justin Beeber / whatever else is unlikely to match their musical taste? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to fix this, I'd investigate putting some real protection around your resources.  I.E., `http://example.com:7000/foo.mp3` should not be directly accessible.  You could put it behind a server that forces something like one-time keys, such that it would need to be requested as `http://example.com:7000/foo.mp3?key=1234`, where `1234` is a [cryptographically secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) random key.  Your web server that loads *your* flash application would generate this key, pass it along as a variable into the flash application, then authorize this key on the server that is serving your media content (possibly the same server).  Especially if the resource server and the HTML server are the same, this could also easily be done with HTTP cookies.

Now, this won't prevent someone from loading your HTML to obtain an authorized key.  However, if you properly embed the key within the HTML, it will at least be a significant deterrent.  (If you would require authentication and authorization for this HTML page, you'd pretty much have everything covered.)

Using `crossdomain.xml` or any other similar approach is placing the security of your resources in control of the client instead of the server - which is never a good idea.

Comment: For sure I can do that, limit the access by some hash tokens, but that's not what I want, and it doesn't solve the problem. The problem those player caused is that they keep sending HTTP request to my server, they are designed to reload resource until success. And some guys embedded player in their web, then users open those pages and leave the player there keep sending HTTP requests. I mean, it's more like kind of DDOS attack, rather than access control problem. To stop them, I need to let the Flash player know they should not access my http resource.

Comment: What if they're using a player that doesn't respect or isn't configured to use something like crossdomain.xml?  (Not saying that this is exactly what you're observing, but it should be considered.)